# How to fix this org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

How to fix this below issue. I am using chrome version 80.0.3987.132 and driver version 80.0.3987.106

```
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 7109
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
    [1584378090.358][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
    Mar 16, 2020 10:31:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    [1584378094.793][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378094.896][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.000][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.105][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.206][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.312][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.418][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.579][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.682][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.786][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.888][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378095.989][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.091][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.194][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.295][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.397][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.500][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.603][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.708][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.811][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378096.912][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.014][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.121][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.222][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.324][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.426][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.530][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.633][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.737][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.840][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378097.942][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.043][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.144][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.248][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.351][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.455][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.559][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.660][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.766][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378098.869][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.046][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.147][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.252][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.354][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.455][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.559][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.661][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.764][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.869][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378099.970][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378100.073][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378100.184][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378100.300][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378100.416][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    [1584378101.208][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
    FAILED: Loginpagetitletest
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.tq.qa.PageObjects.Pg01_LoginPage.validateLoginpageTitle(Pg01_LoginPage.java:35)
        at com.tq.qa.TestCases.LoginPageTest.Loginpagetitletest(LoginPageTest.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```